# ¿Cómo paso argumentos al código de un script .CSX?

Tags: c#

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 [incluye la herramienta CSI.EXE](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update1-vs#Csharp), que permite ejecutar scripts .CSX, escritos directamente en C#. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo leer los argumentos pasados a CSI.EXE en la línea de comandos y dirigidos al código que se ejecuta, no a la propia herramienta. Sé que debe haber alguna manera, porque al ejecutar `csi /?` aparece lo siguiente como parte de la ayuda:

> --  Indicates that the remaining arguments should not be treated as options.

es decir,

> --  Indica que el resto de argumentos no deben ser tratados como opciones.

por lo que al ejecutar `csi MiPrograma.csx /foo /bar -- fizz buzz`, debe haber alguna forma de que el código tenga acceso a `fizz buzz`.

He mirado incluso [el código fuente de CSI.EXE](http://source.roslyn.io/#csi/Csi.cs,16) y de las clases asociadas, pero no encuentro ninguna pista. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para leer los parámetros puedes usar la función [GetCommandLineArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Por ejemplo el código

```
foreach(var p in System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
    Console.WriteLine(p);
```

produce la salida

```
...>csi test.csx -- pepe foo
csi
test.csx
--
pepe
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar la respuesta de josejuan, la siguiente sentencia me da los argumentos pasados para el código, sin el `--` ni los argumentos anteriores:

```
var arguments =
    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    .SkipWhile(arg => arg  != "--")
    .Skip(1)
    .ToArray();
```